# Segregate the row based on the date time column per each month

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have the following table in sql server database environment.

the format of start date MM/DD/YYYY.

[image]

I need the result to be like the following table.

based on start date column the record should segregated to each month in the period between start date and end date

[image]

Comment: What type are columns [Start Date] and [End Date]?

Comment: the type of both columns is datetime

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, startdate as dte, enddate
      from t
      union all
      select id, 
             dateadd(day, 1, eomonth(dte)),
             enddate
      from t
      where eomonth(dte) < enddate
     )
select id, dte,
       lead(dte, 1, enddate) over (partition by id order by dte)
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Gordon Linoff
Using CTE I have got the following result
[image]

My code

```
WITH cte 
     AS (SELECT 1                          AS id, 
                Cast('2010-01-20' AS DATE) AS trg, 
                Cast('2010-01-20' AS DATE) AS strt_dte, 
                Cast('2010-03-15' AS DATE) AS end_dte 
         UNION ALL 
         SELECT id, 
                Dateadd(day, 1, Eomonth (trg)), 
                strt_dte, 
                end_dte 
         FROM   cte 
         WHERE  Eomonth(trg) < end_dte) 
SELECT id, 
       trg, 
       strt_dte, 
       end_dte, 
       Lead (trg, 1, end_dte) 
         OVER ( 
           partition BY id 
           ORDER BY trg) AS lead_result 
FROM   cte
```